# How replace beamer graphics by itemize?

Tags: beamer, overlays

In a Beamer frame with two "pages" (the second one appearing after mouse click) I have:

- On first page an `itemize` environment with 3 `\item` followed by a picture added with `includegraphics`
- On second page the same `itemize` environment with the same 3 `\item` and I want to replace the picture by a 4th `\item`

My problem is about how keep the same position and size of all elements in the two pages. I am able to replace my graphics by a 4th `item` using `<1>` on the include graphics and `<2>` on the 4th itemize but the layout of the frame changes between the two pages. How can I avoid that ?

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example to illustrate? My first response is to top-align the slide content by supplying the `[t]` option to `\begin{frame}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\overlayarea`:

```
\overlayarea{<width>}{<height>}
```

A simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{6cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> First item.
\item<1-> Second item.
\item<1-> Third item.

\only<1>{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
\item<2> Fourth item.
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]